# Necessary and sufficient condition on a polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ for the ring $\frac{\mathbb Q[x]}{p(x)}$ to contain non zero nilpotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Necessary and sufficient condition on a polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ for the ring $\frac{\mathbb Q[x]}{p(x)}$ to contain non zero nilpotent.

My try:If $<p(x)>$ will be set of all nilpotent elements of $\mathbb Q[x]$,then it will contain no nonzero nilpotent?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ has no nonzero nilpotents.

Comment: Can you give even one example of a nonzero nilpotent element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: no, there is no non zero nilpotent in a field.

Comment: @Mathemagic: $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is not a field.

Comment: yes ,an integral domain

Comment: Try a few examples with an actual $p(x)$. The hint in the posted answer by lhf is also a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

The rings $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q[x]$ are similar in many respects:

> The nilpotent elements of $\mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z$ correspond to the multiples of the radical of $n$, which is the product of all primes that divide $n$.

The equivalent statement for $\mathbb Q[x]/(p)$ is exactly the same:

> The nilpotent elements of $\mathbb Q[x]/(p(x))$ correspond to the multiples of the radical of $p(x)$, which is the product of all irreducible polynomials  that divide $p(x)$.

Comment: $Z_n $ has a nonzero nilpotent element if and only if $n$ is divisible by the square of some prime.

Comment: @MatheMagic, right. Now, how does that translate to $\mathbb Q[x]$?

Comment: Sorry sir, will you please explain it in detail?

Comment: @MatheMagic: What ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ might be an analogous ideal to $(3^2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., will induce a nonzero nilpotent element after modding out)?

Comment: @Mathemagic: Said differently, _why_ does $Z_9$ have a nonzero nilpotent element? In particular, what is an example of a nonzero nilpotent element in $Z_9$?

Comment: 3 is the non zero nilpotent

Comment: Right, $3$ is nilpotent in $Z_9$ (as is $6$). So now _try_ some examples for $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/p(x)$ _might_ be analogous to $Z/9Z$. You have to do some work too.

Comment: It might help to write $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ in the form $\mathbb{Z}/(9)$, where $(9)$ denotes the principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $9$.